# .Net Core Making a Proxy

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to develop a simple proxy that is suppose to forward api requests between my first application and my second application. For Get requests it works great but i'm now trying to forward a request with an actual body and it's not working out. I thought about using a middelware for this but i don't think using a middelware would solve this particular issue.

here's my ProxyController:

```
[HttpGet("/api/corporations/{*url}")]
public async Task<string> GetCorporations(string url)
{
    var result = await _httpClient.GetAsync("SomeCoolUrl");
    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}

[HttpPatch("/api/corporations/{*url}")]
public async Task<string> PatchCorporations(string url, [FromBody]object body)
{
    var result = await HttpClientExtension.PatchAsync(_httpClient, "SomeCoolUrl", new StringContent(body.ToString()));
    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

I implemented PatchAsync (in HttpClientExtension) like this:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchAsync(HttpClient httpClient, string url, StringContent content)
{
    return await httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), url) { Content = content });
}
```

The problem is that i get an unsupported Media Type when sending the patch request undoubtedly  because object.tostring() isn't a valid json. But i can't figure out what type of object to use to properly retain the patch request body. if i try String or StringContent instead of object they are always null. I want to keep it generic so i can't define an object matching a specific body like i normally would do.

I am using AspNetCore 1.1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed object that is supposed to be used.

The problem was `new StringContent(body.ToString())` is not a proper request payload. I replaced it with `new StringContent(content: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), encoding: Encoding.UTF8, mediaType: "application/json");` and it works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

"Unsupported media type" is going to be the result of your application not being able to bind its PatchCorporations based on the content-type of the request to *it*. Use a `string body` instead of `object body` so that ASP.NET can match the HTTP request to it. Typically, [content negotiation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation) will use content-type of "application/json" or "application/xml" (for example) to automatically serialize/de-serialize the HTTP request into the correct controller method via [parameter binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody).

Comment: the debugger steps into it fine. when body is an object body it is not null. but it is null when it's a string. Unsupported media type is in result.

Comment: According to this maybe it's not suppose to have a json content type ? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789